# How to create new stream from Redis cache

Tags: php, slim, psr-4, slim-4

I am storing image inside redis.

```php
$image = $cache->remember($key, null, function () use ($request, $args) {
            $image = $this->get('image');
            $storage = $this->get('storage');

            return $image->load($storage->get($args['path'])->read())
                        ->withFilters($request->getQueryParams())
                        ->stream();
        });
```

and trying to get it back:

```php
return (new Response())
                ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
                ->withBody($image);
```

it gives me this error:

```php
Return value of Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse::__invoke() 
must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface, string returned
```

`$image` variable is bytes of that image. how can I convert those bytes to a stream?

Comment: The Response should be an instance of `Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface` and `$image` should be an instance of `Psr\Http\Message\StreamInterface`.

Comment: i understood the error, my question was how do I can convert text string to actual stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create a stream from a string, you can use the Slim's implementation of `Psr\Http\Message\StreamFactoryInterface` (see [PSR-17: HTTP Factories](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-17/), or any other external library implementing the same interface (like [laminas-diactoros](https://github.com/laminas/laminas-diactoros/blob/master/src/StreamFactory.php)).

Using the Slim library, it should be something like this:

```
<?php

use Slim\Psr7\Response;
use Slim\Psr7\Factory\StreamFactory;

// The string to create a stream from.
$image = $cache->remember($key, null, function () use ($request, $args) {
    //...
});

// Create the stream factory.
$streamFactory = new StreamFactory();

// Create a stream from the provided string.
$stream = $streamFactory->createStream($image);

// Create a response.
$response = (new Response())
                ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png')
                ->withBody($stream);

// Do whatever with the response.
```

Alternatively, you could use the method `StreamFactory::createStreamFromFile`:

```
<?php

// ...

/*
 * Create a stream with read-write access:
 *
 *  'r+': Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file.
 *  'b': Force to binary mode.
 */
$stream = $streamFactory->createStreamFromFile('php://temp', 'r+b');

// Write the string to the stream.
$stream->write($image);

// ...
```